# SearchView search_plate not extending to full width

Tags: android, searchview

I have a SearchView in my toolbar that i created like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    tools:context=".ui.search.SearchActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/topbar_gradient"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/topbar_gradient"
            android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            android:contentInsetLeft="-16dp"
            android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                android:gravity="left"
                android:maxWidth="1000dp"
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_search"
                app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                app:goIcon="@null"
                app:voiceIcon="@null"
                app:commitIcon="@null"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/double_spacing"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

(...)
</RelativeLayout>
```

This shows up like this:

[image]

So the SearchView does expand to full width, but not the textview within it, which by using the Layout Inspector I found out is within a LinearLayout called search_plate, which is in a LinearLayout called search_edit_frame that is not expanding:

[image]

Now as much as I try I cant get the Search bar to start closer to the back button nor the Search Edit Text to expand to full width.

I tried this based off other answers:

```
var findViewById = searchView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(searchView.context.resources.getIdentifier("android:id/search_edit_frame", null, null))
findViewById?.layoutParams?.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
```

But it cant ever find a view with this id.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47530355/8089770

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28021968/8089770

Comment: this does not answer my question

Answer (score 1):

The following does the trick:

```
searchView.setMaxWidth( Integer.MAX_VALUE );
```

or use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SearchView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```